# set onClickListener edit text listview

Tags: java, android, listview

Hello at all the community,
i've a listview with a custom adapter that consists by one textview and one edit text. i set the text for the edit text into the adapter but in my acivity (listview) i want to set the onClickListener at this edit text. ive this code for my getView method

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(view == null) {
            holder = new Holder();
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_adapter, null);
            holder.textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            holder.editText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
            view.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (Holder)view.getTag();
        }

        holder.editText.setText("My text");
        holder.textView.setText("text");

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
        return false;
    }
```

i disablet the click on listview with the isEnabled method because I will not be able to click on the list. in my activity i've only the listview so if i want to set onclicklistener on the edit text of the adapter how can i do this?

```
public MyAdapterClass(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> list) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.list = list;
    this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: Paste full code of `Adapter` Please?

Comment: updated my question with the constructor

Comment: need to click event of EditText?

Comment: You will have to add the onclick listener to each edit text in the list view adapter. Bear in mind that the views are recycled, so a given onclicklistener may actually be tied to more than one object in your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use this

```
holder.editText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //do something
    }

});

@Override
public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please do something like :

```
private OnClickListener cl;
public MyAdapterClass(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> list, OnClickListener cl) {
super(context, textViewResourceId, list);
// TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
this.list = list;
this.context = context;
this.cl = cl;
}
```

then in on `getView()`set it to `EditText` :

```
holder.editText.setOnClickListener(cl);
```

finally set set an put `OnClickListener()` like :

```
OnClickListener cl = new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   // Logic of Click goes Here.
}
};
```

where you are setting `Adapter` to 
`ListView`, like :

```
adapter = MyAdapterClass(Activity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list, cl);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```